# Using Poco library, how to set different log levels per channel in a splitter channel logger?

Tags: logging, poco-libraries

What I have now:

- Windows Event channel
- Simple File channel
- Splitter channel to route to both channels
- Root logger set with PRIO_INFORMATION level

.

```
//Windows Event Log
Poco::EventLogChannel* elChannel = new Poco::EventLogChannel("App");

//Simple file Log
Poco::SimpleFileChannel* sfChannel = new Poco::SimpleFileChannel();
sfChannel->setProperty("path", "log.txt");
sfChannel->setProperty("rotation", "10 M");

//Splitter Channel 
Poco::SplitterChannel* sChannel = new Poco::SplitterChannel();
sChannel->addChannel(sfChannel);
sChannel->addChannel(elChannel);

logger().root().setChannel(sChannel);
logger().root().setLevel(Poco::Message::PRIO_INFORMATION);
```

I would like to have different log levels per channel in the splitter:

- Windows Event channel level: WARNING
- File channel level: INFORMATION

This way only messages above WARNING would go to Windows Event Viewer.

Could this be achieved in some way using standard Poco::Logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging level is per Logger, not per Channel, so you will have to have two loggers. See [Logger example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/samples/Logger/src/Logger.cpp#L46). To avoid inconvenience of having to log the same thing twice, you can write your own "splitter" function that wraps the loggers and logs the same messages to both.

Comment: is there a way to this through a config file? Can easily create both loggers but how would the application know which one to use and when to use both?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You can configure loggers in the config file and you have to write your own wrapper for them, which simply forwards log messages to both loggers; messages are filtered and routed accordingly by each logger.

Comment: The link is dead, here is the [correct one](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/3fc3e5f5b8462f7666952b43381383a79b8b5d92/Foundation/samples/Logger/src/Logger.cpp#L44)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.

```
#include "Poco/Logger.h"
using Poco::Logger;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Logger& logger = Logger::get("TestLogger");
    logger.information("This is an informational message");
    logger.warning("This is a warning message");
    return 0;
}
```

More details:

https://pocoproject.org/slides/110-Logging.pdf

Here are some valuable slides about other Poco subsystems

https://pocoproject.org/slides/

I hope the links won't be broken :)